# What is not persisted in a database backup / restore? (SQL Server 2005)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, backup

If I take a backup of a database on a SQL 2005 Server, and then restore that backup to a different (new) database on the same database server instance, what things will not be persisted (things like cached execution plans, statistics etc...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Plans will be recreated at first run.

Otherwise, everything database level will be there except where it interacts at the instance level, such as:

- replication
- backup jobs/schedules
- maintenance plans/schedules
- login mappings to users

For a standard, everyday database, you've no worries.

Comment: also any custom stored procs that have been added to the "master" database

Comment: good point, I'd say this "instance level" though

Answer (score 3):

**Orphaned Users** are often the result of restoring MS SQL Server databases.  Here's an article on [fixing orphaned users](http://www.lockergnome.com/sqlsquirrel/2009/05/16/fixing-orphaned-users-in-sql-server-2005/).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I have been doing it incorrectly or not, however, when I do a restore it never seems to carry over user information.  I end up needed to re add them manually (or through another script).